# I've recently been working on importing Call Of Duty animations. But when I export the animations into Unity, they get totally broken

Tags: unity-game-engine, maya

[Animation-Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcwpl.jpg)

The animation looks great inside of Maya, but not in Unity.
I've fixed all of the exporting errors already.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong :P Note that Maya uses a differently handed coordinate system .. could this be an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't enough information within your question to provide an absolute answer. It could be down to one of many problems...

1. Are you using expressions?
2. Are you using IK chains?
3. Are you animating rotate or scale pivots?
4. Have you tried baking the animation data first?
5. Are you sure the exporter works?
6. Is the character rig known to work within the game? (or is this your own?)

Typically exporters for games will bake the Maya joint model down to simple TRS animations. Sadly there are some combinations of scale/rotate pivots that are simply impossible to convert into TRS, and still maintain correct animation interpolation. Assuming the exporter works correctly, I'm going to guess that may be the cause?

Comment: You're right. This problem only occurs when exporting directly to unity. Thanks for the answer :)